# How can I use my own classes as edmx model classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6.

I'd like to use my own domain classes as edmx model classes, so I erased the  tt generated model classes and changed edmx build Action to None.

When I try to perform a select I get MetadataException

```
DbContext context = new DbContext("name=BaseObjectsEntities");
var u = context.Set<User>().Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Works perfectly with generated tt model classes, but not with my own classes.

What should I do or configurate to link my classes with edmx.

ps: my classes already have their class and properties names equal to edmx ones.

Comment: `Works perfectly with generated tt model classes, but not with my own classes.` <= so what happens exactly? Remember, we can't see your computer monitor so a description of what **is** happening and how that is different from the expected behavior is appreciated.

Comment: If I dont delete tt classes and change the object 

from:

-  context.Set<MyOwnClass>  

to:
-  context.Set<GeneratedTTClass> 

it will work, but I have to delete generated and use my own classes.

Comment: Have you considered stepping over to code first where you define your classes and mapping in c# instead of a designer or using T4 template?

Comment: I will not use T4, but I need use DbFirst, as I said I would like to use my own classes that I already have, I just want to know a way to make edmx look to these classes as he looks to generated ones.

I think it is not working because EF can't find correspondent models, and I need to make it look to my domain classes and use it as model.

Comment: why not use code first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem,

These are the steps I did:

- If you still haven't

  > Create your own domain classes;
- Create Database

  > create tables
- Create Edmx

  > Now listen carefully, when you finalize the creating of edmx, visual studio will open edmx in design mode, don't save, don't close, don't do anything but change the name of entity models and their properties (in diagram block that represents the model), make sure the name of entity and It's properties are as specified in domain, I will tell later why not save or close.

> Don't save or close the design window yet, if you do this and your domain classes are in the same project they will be overwritted by the .tt classes that are generated when emdx is created.
>
> Delete All .tt file that is agregated to emdx and don't save.

- Now right click in Edmx > Properties

> Erase whatever is writted in "Custom Tool" and make sure the build Action is EntityDeploy
>
> When you remove the text writted in Custom Tool, click enter, then build solution

Now it will work.

- I forgot to mention that if these steps does not work, there is a secret step:

> delete the project from visual studio and from project folder, recreate it, and restart the initial steps.